# Upload a file into Folder within Style Library using PowerShell in SP 2013

Tags: powershell, file-upload

How to Upload a .css file on the folder  within the Style Library of my site collection using PowerShell. I am having a  style file called style_bg.css.
How to get the folder within the   style library through powershell.I have written the below line of code.

```
     [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName 
      ("Microsoft.SharePoint")
        if((Get-PSSnapin | Where {$_.Name -eq   
        "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"}) -eq $null) {
        Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell;
          }
       #Site Collection where you want to upload files
       $siteCollUrl  = "http://srvr1:123/sites/Geology/"

         $libraryName = "Style Library" #  can i enter folder name here ?

       #Physical/Network location of files
       $reportFilesLocation  = "C:\Maddy\Scripts\Styles"
      $spSourceWeb = Get-SPWeb $siteCollUrl;
     $spSourceList = $spSourceWeb.Lists[$libraryName];
     if($spSourceList -eq $null)
       {
       Write-Host "The Library $libraryName could not be found."
       return;
      }
        $files = ([System.IO.DirectoryInfo] (Get-Item  
      $reportFilesLocation)).GetFiles()
     foreach($file in $files)
    {
      #Open file
         $fileStream = ([System.IO.FileInfo] (Get-Item 
      $file.FullName)).OpenRead()
        #Add file
       $folder =  $spSourceWeb.getfolder($libraryName)
        Write-Host "Copying file $file to $libraryName..."
```

But i am not able to insert into the particular sub folder within the style library using the  above. I am stuck with where I am missing. And if its checked out after insert , how to check in and publish.

Answer (score 1):

For uploading file to a particular folder you need to initialize it as

```
$folderName = "FolderToUpload";
$folder =  $spSourceList.getfolder($spSourceWeb.Url + "/" + $libraryName + "/" + $folderName)
```

For file check in you can use

```
$spFile.CheckIn("Comments", 1)
```

To Approve File you can use

```
$spFile.Approve("Comments")
```

Comment: thanks. Am getting the error "The file "http://srvr1:123/sites/Geology/Style Library/myfolder/style_bg.css" 
is not checked out.  You must first check out this document before making changes."

Comment: You can checkout using `$spFile.CheckOut()`

Comment: $folder = $web.getfolder($docLibrary.Title+"/"+$cssfoldername) 
              Write-Host    $_.Name  " ..is the file name...."       
    $spFile = $folder.Files.Add($folder.Url + "/" + $_.Name, $contents, $true)    Write-Host "checking out file"
                $spFile.CheckOut()  want to know, whether should i check out the already existing  file before adding files to folder or after caling this function folder.files.add() ? i am trying to overriding the already existing file with few changes in my css file. There are some 40 + site collections so,I can't add this css file manually.

Comment: You should checkout before Adding file.